# excel vba programming for list comparison of same sheet

Tags: excel, vba

here the two list in a sheet i want the list with data of list 1 and extra data from list 2. please suggest the code. thanks

list 1 (column a,b,c)

```
A       B        C
name    class    marks
a       1        12
b       2        13
c       5        14
d       4        15
```

list 2 (column d e f)

```
D       E       F
name    class   marks
z        2      4
d        6      2
c        8      6
x        9      8
```

result (keep list 1 and extra from list 2 in column g h i)

```
G       H       I
name    class   marks
a        1      12
b        2      13
c        5      14
d        4      15
z        2      4
x        9      8
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! As you may have skipped the intro for this site: SO is not supposed to deliver full solutions, but rather helping you with problems in existing code. “Code this for me” questions are generally frowned upon around here, however, we’d love to help you learn! For further information on posting a question, you might want to have a look at this: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I've redone the tabulation, but I can't see how the result is derived. Could you add more details of what's actually required there?

Comment: Why is d from list 2 added but c from list 2 is not?

Comment: I really sorry to explain that the result table was wrong, now updated (which include all record from list 1 and extra name found from list 2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How's something like this:

```
    Sub test()
    Dim lastRow1 As Integer, lastRow2 As Integer, newLastRow As Integer, lastCol As Integer, i As Integer
    Dim headers() As Variant

    ReDim headers(2)

    headers() = Array("Name", "Class", "Marks")


    lastRow1 = Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
    lastRow2 = Cells(1, 4).End(xlDown).Row

    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range
    Set rng1 = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(lastRow1, 3))
    Set rng2 = Range(Cells(2, 4), Cells(lastRow2, 6))

    Range(Cells(1, 7), Cells(1, 9)) = headers()

    newLastRow = 2
    rng1.Copy Range(Cells(newLastRow, 7), Cells(newLastRow, 7))
    newLastRow = Cells(2, 7).End(xlDown).Row + 1
    rng2.Copy Range(Cells(newLastRow, 7), Cells(newLastRow, 7))

    End Sub
```

Edit: After discussion (see comments below), use this code:

```
Sub test()
Dim lastRow1 As Integer, lastRow2 As Integer, newLastRow As Integer, lastCol As Integer, i As Integer
Dim headers() As Variant
Dim cel As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

ReDim headers(2)

headers() = Array("Name", "Class", "Marks")


lastRow1 = Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
lastRow2 = Cells(1, 4).End(xlDown).Row

Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range
Set rng1 = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(lastRow1, 3))
Set rng2 = Range(Cells(2, 4), Cells(lastRow2, 6))

'Search List2's name column to delete any duplicate names that are in Col A.
For i = 2 To lastRow2
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(lastRow1, 1)), Cells(i, 4).Value) > 0 Then
        Debug.Print "Delete"
        Range(Cells(i, 4), Cells(i, 7)).Delete shift:=xlUp
        i = i - 1
    End If
Next i

Range(Cells(1, 7), Cells(1, 9)) = headers()

lastRow2 = Cells(1, 4).End(xlDown).Row
newLastRow = 2
rng1.Copy Range(Cells(newLastRow, 7), Cells(newLastRow, 7))
newLastRow = Cells(2, 7).End(xlDown).Row + 1

Set rng2 = Range(Cells(2, 4), Cells(lastRow2, 6))
rng2.Copy Range(Cells(newLastRow, 7), Cells(newLastRow, 7))

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your coding but we require all record from list 1 and extra record based on name from list 2, please modify it.

Comment: @Dr.Rabindrakumarsingh - can you clarify what you mean? The code above does it for me: [Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/A7UNaRP.jpg).  Note: Columns G, H, and I are blank before running the macro.  It adds the lists to that range.

Comment: This code merge all records but we need only list 1 and extra name record from list 2 which does not include name c & d, due to already present in list 1. in result we need no duplicates name. Thanks

Comment: we need no duplicates name in result so please get all record from list 1 and from list 2 get only those record which which name is not matched with list 1.this code merge all record

Comment: Which record though do you want to keep? In List 1 you have D with class 4 and marks 15, but in List 2, D has class 6 and marks 2...which one should stay and which should be removed? How do you determine that?  Or do you combine the classes and marks? (I.e. Name D, class (4+6), marks (15+2)?

Comment: No sir i just want to keep list 1 and discard common name from list 2 like we keep only d with class 4 and marks 15 and discard list 2 d class 6 and mark 2. finally we keep list 1 and discard from list 2. Thanks

Comment: this code merge whole record but we want only full record of list 1 and uncommon name record from list 2.

Comment: so nice of you sir, its works as per my requirement.